# Synonomize tags on Meta: on-topic vs. site-scope

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, meta

We have two tags here on Meta that seem to cover exactly the same content.

- [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic)
- [site-scope](/questions/tagged/site-scope)

Could a moderator please add on-topic as a synonym of [site-scope](/questions/tagged/site-scope)?

Comment: The [tag:on-topic] tag has more questions than site-scope so I made site-scope a synonym of on-topic. If people disagree with this, it can be easily swapped.